# TSQL: Count on outer joined tables is producing incorrect results

Tags: sql-server-2008, t-sql, count, outer-join

Producing a report on SQL Server 2008. I have joined one table with five others using `LEFT OUTER JOIN`. When I run a count against those other tables, I get incorrect data. I know WHY, but I'm unsure how to fix it.

The query is tracking admissions candidates for a school. As they move through the process, they are flagged at each major stage of the process. What I need is to count how many passed through a particular stage in a particular period (year and month). Mostly it works. However, if a candidate passed through ANY stage in the period, that candidate gets "counted" in previous stages as well, even if they happened prior to the queried period. An excellent example is AD_35, where there should be one person for a particular academic program, but the output says 2. When I query ONLY the AD_35 table, I get the correct information. So I know the issue is with the outer join, but I am not sure how to overcome this issue (having tried various criteria in the subquery that generates my named outputs). Should be an easy one for someone... Thanks in advance, and the code is below. The :Year and :Month are for user inputs and would be populated with numeric values (e.g. 2015 1)

CW

```
SELECT DISTINCT 
   ad_candidacy.prog_cde,   
   ad_candidacy.stageyr,   
   ad_candidacy.stagemo,   
   Count (case when (ad_02.stageyr in (:Year, :Year -1, :Year-2) and ad_02.stagemo <= :month) then 1 else null end) as Inquiry,   
   Count (case when (ad_05.stageyr in (:Year, :Year -1, :Year-2) and ad_05.stagemo <= :month) then 1 else null end) as Applied,   
   Count (case when (ad_35.stageyr in (:Year, :Year -1, :Year-2) and ad_35.stagemo <= :month and ad_35.id_num = ad_candidacy.id_num and ad_35.stageyr = ad_candidacy.stageyr and ad_35.stagemo=ad_candidacy.stagemo) then 1 else null end) as Accepted,   
   Count (case when (ad_50.stageyr in (:Year, :Year -1, :Year-2) and ad_50.stagemo <= :month) then 1 else null end) as Matriculated,   
   Count (case when (ad_enroll.stageyr in (:Year, :Year -1, :Year-2) and ad_enroll.stagemo <= :month) then 1 else null end) as Enrolled,   
   ad_candidacy.stagemo_long  
FROM 
   ad_candidacy 
LEFT OUTER JOIN 
   ad_02 ON ad_candidacy.id_num = ad_02.id_num 
LEFT OUTER JOIN 
   ad_05 ON ad_candidacy.id_num = ad_05.id_num 
LEFT OUTER JOIN 
   ad_35 ON ad_candidacy.id_num = ad_35.id_num 
LEFT OUTER JOIN 
   ad_enroll ON ad_candidacy.id_num = ad_enroll.id_num 
LEFT OUTER JOIN 
   ad_50 ON ad_candidacy.id_num = ad_50.id_num  
WHERE 
   (ad_candidacy.stageyr in (:Year, :Year -1, :Year-2) ) 
   AND ( ad_candidacy.stagemo <= :Month )   
GROUP BY 
   ad_candidacy.prog_cde,   
   ad_candidacy.stageyr,   
   ad_candidacy.stagemo,   
   ad_candidacy.stagemo_long  
ORDER BY 
   ad_candidacy.stageyr ASC
```

Comment: Are you saying if a candidate is counted as "Accepted", then they're counted as "Applied" as well even if they applied more than 2 years ago? I don't see how. Or if you're saying a candidate applied last year and got accepted this year, then it makes sense they're counted twice.

Comment: I am saying the second. Why does it make sense? (yes, I need some schooling here, ha!) The candidate was accepted in December 2014, and enrolled in January 2015. If I query the AD_35 (accepted) table, I see the December date. If I query and restrict to only January 2015, the candidate does not show up. However, when I run the above query which includes the join, there is the candidate with Acceptance and Enrollment in January 2015. I would think the subquery in the Count (case... statement would resolve this, but no.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Joining multiple tables requires to think about the join conditions. It is possible that the second table has multiple rows for the same row. To ensure that you do end up with duplicates, you can search through the second table in a subquery before joining to the first table.

```
SELECT a.Name, 
       b.Total
FROM table1 as a
LEFT OUTER JOIN ( SELECT table1Id, Total = COUNT(b.some_measure) from table2 group by table1Id)as b ON a.table1Id = b.table1Id
```

Comment: Agreed on thinking about join conditions. Querying the second table alone gives me the correct information. However, your code sample has given me some additional fodder for reworking the OUTER JOIN logic and I am working through variations on that now.

Answer (score 0):

Ako's response pointed me in the right direction. I was using subqueries, but his example led to the correct output. Below is the working version of the code. Thanks!

```
SELECT DISTINCT 
   ad_candidacy.prog_cde,   
   ad_candidacy.stageyr,   
   ad_candidacy.stagemo, 
   ad_candidacy.StageMo_Long,
   COUNT (case when (Inquiry IS NOT NULL) then 1 else null end) as Inquiry,
   COUNT (case when (Applied IS NOT NULL) then 1 else null end) as Applied,
   count (case when (Accepted is not null) then 1 else null end) as Accepted,
   COUNT (case when (Matriculated IS NOT NULL) then 1 else null end) as Matriculated,
   count (case when (Enrolled is not null) then 1 else null end) as Enrolled
FROM 
   ad_candidacy
LEFT OUTER JOIN
 (select id_num, Inquiry = COUNT (id_num) from ad_02 where stageyr in (:year, :year-1, :year-2) and StageMo <= :month group by id_num) as ad_02 on ad_candidacy.id_num = ad_02.id_num     
LEFT OUTER JOIN
 (select id_num, Accepted = COUNT (id_num) from ad_35 where stageyr in (:year, :year-1, :year-2) and StageMo <= :month group by id_num) as ad_35 on ad_candidacy.id_num = ad_35.id_num    
LEFT OUTER JOIN
 (select id_num, Applied = COUNT (id_num) from ad_05 where stageyr in (:year, :year-1, :year-2) and StageMo <= :month group by id_num) as ad_05 on ad_candidacy.id_num = ad_05.id_num    
LEFT OUTER JOIN
 (select id_num, Matriculated = COUNT (id_num) from ad_50 where stageyr in (:year, :year-1, :year-2) and StageMo <= :month group by id_num) as ad_50 on ad_candidacy.id_num = ad_50.id_num   
LEFT OUTER JOIN
 (select id_num, Enrolled = COUNT (id_num) from ad_enroll where stageyr in (:year, :year-1, :year-2) and StageMo <= :month group by id_num) as ad_enroll on ad_candidacy.id_num = ad_enroll.id_num  
WHERE 
   (ad_candidacy.stageyr in (:year, :year-1, :year-2) ) 
   AND ( ad_candidacy.stagemo <= :month )   
GROUP BY 
   ad_candidacy.prog_cde,   
   ad_candidacy.stageyr,   
   ad_candidacy.stagemo,   
   ad_candidacy.stagemo_long
```